# How to use factory bean to create beans in Camel flow

Tags: spring, apache, spring-boot, apache-camel

If I have a spring factory bean can I use this factory bean to create my beans within Camel route ?

```
<bean id="factoryBean" class = "ABC">

<route id ="someId">
    <bean id = "someBean" ref ="factoryBean" method = "factoryMethod">
    <bean ref = "someBean" method = "someMethod1" />
    <bean ref = "someBean" method = "someMethod2" />
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in the `<route>` as it can only call a bean by either the id or the FQN classname. But a factory bean you can setup in Spring or OSGi Blueprint and then give that an id, which you can then just call from a Camel route.